# Stored Procedure call not working Entrity Framework 5 code first

Tags: sql-server-2008, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a stored procedure in my database:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeletePaySlip]
    @PayRunId BIGINT,
    @EmployeeId BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PaySlipId BIGINT   

    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @PaySlipId = Id 
        FROM PYREmployeePaySlip 
        WHERE PayRunId = @PayRunId AND EmployeeId = @EmployeeId

        BEGIN TRANSACTION t1

        IF  @PaySlipId IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM PYREmployeePaySlipDetail WHERE PaySlipId = @PaySlipId
            DELETE FROM PYREmployeePaySlip WHERE Id = @PaySlipId
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION t1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1
    END CATCH; 

END
```

If I execute the stored procedure from SQL query window, it works.

Now I am trying to call the stored procedure from C# code

```
 public bool DeleteEmployeePaySlip(long payRunId, long employeeId)
 {
            bool success = true;
            var sqlparamPayRunId = new SqlParameter("@PayRunId", payRunId);
            var sqlparamEmployeeId = new SqlParameter("@EmployeeId", employeeId);

            using (var dbContext = new CRMDbContext())
            {                
                try
                {
                    var res = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Object>("EXEC DeletePaySlip @PayRunId, @EmployeeId",
                                                       sqlparamPayRunId,
                                                       sqlparamEmployeeId);
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return success;
        }
```

When I call the method above, it does not throw any error. But the stored procedure not seems to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.103).aspx), the expression

```
 dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Object>("EXEC DeletePaySlip @PayRunId, @EmployeeId",
                                                   sqlparamPayRunId,
                                                   sqlparamEmployeeId);
```

... will "[c]reate a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given generic type".

So what it returns (your object `res`) will be of this type:

```
DbRawSqlQuery<object>
```

This isn't (yet) the results of the query: it's more like an encapsulation of a query.  You won't get the results (and, most importantly from your point of view, **the SQL won't execute**) until you enumerate it.

But actually, it looks to me like you're using the wrong method to execute your stored procedure.  It's not a query at all, but a data manipulation.  So try this instead:

```
 dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC DeletePaySlip @PayRunId, @EmployeeId",
                                                   sqlparamPayRunId,
                                                   sqlparamEmployeeId);
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.103).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I already have tried ExecuteSqlCommand() method as my stored procedure is a non query. It worked!